# jQuery Timepicker reset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, time, datepicker

Someone know how to reset the jQuery Timepicker http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ ?
I need to set the Hours and the Minutes to 0 before open it up.

I tried to do that but it doesn't work:

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    hour:0, minute: 0});
```

I set the value of the bind textbox to empty but If I show the timepicker, it still have the previously value setted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually datepickers are associated to a textbox element. Try modifying the value of that element to have the date (usually today date) at 00:00.

Comment: Is not DatePicker ! Is about TimePicker !

Comment: But it's still bound to a textbox isn't it? Instead of emptying it try to give it a time value of 00:00

Comment: Yes, giving it a value of 00:00, timepicker opens with all slides from 0. But no way to set to black the textbox and open the timepicker form 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `alwaysSetTime` to false:

> alwaysSetTime – Default: true - Always have a time set internally, even before user has chosen one.

From: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The solution is not good enough(Using some internal variables).

Works for me though.

```
[tong@localhost javascripts]$ cat jquery-ui-timepicker-clear-button.js
(function($){
    var old_fn = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;

    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
        old_fn.call(this, inst);

        var buttonPane = $(this).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

        $("<button type='button' class='ui-datepicker-clean ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all'>Clear</button>").appendTo(buttonPane).click(function(ev) {
            inst.input.val('');
            $(inst.settings.altField).val('');
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `defaultValue` to `"00:00"`.

It worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

Find this $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) addon.js file and add this code to clear input.

```
  var buttonPane = $(this).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

  $("<button type='button' class='ui-datepicker-clean ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all'>Clear</button>").appendTo(buttonPane).click(function(ev) {
                    inst.input.val('');
    });
```